# Why the dynamically generated inputs return NaN?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap-modal

I've created a modal that returns all number input elements to generate in HTML, but when i insert a number inside, if i write the array (example: {{ ng_model_m[i] }}) inside ngFor, it will return the value, but if i write the ngModel (example: sm.m_prova), it will return NaN.

Project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jbzmnq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fschemamasse-comp.component.ts

**UPDATE**:
When i generate ngModel, i generate also name attribute and i've seen in "Inspect Element" that there isn't name attribute inside the element input, but there is ng-reflect-name and if a print on console by event.target.name, it doesn't print nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two thinks about ngb-model, when you receive the promise you need use `then((resultIfClose)=>{...},(resultIfDismmis)=>{...}`

If you don't want to make nothing when use activeModal.dismiss include a empty function

```
modalRef.result
    .then((res) =>{
     ...
         },
     ()=>{} //<--this
    );
```

Second, "res" is the value you pass in close function, in your stackblitz you pass a string 'prova' and want to iterate as it was an array

Comment: yes, i had to edit it on Stackblitz because there were http calls to my server.

Comment: you can simulate a http call using 'rxjs' of, e.g. return of('value') or return of(['value1','value2')

Comment: i've never used rxjs